# Select option not being displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an HTML web page where on the top of it are some menu options and after to that in a box I want to display some list items. I have used the below code to achieve the same:

```
<body>
<div id="admin">
<div id="header">
<span id="show_all" onclick="showAll();" class="nolite">All</span>
<span id="show_words" onclick="showWords();" class="nolite">Blocked Words</span>
<span id="show_ip" onclick="showIP();" class="nolite">Blocked IP</span>
<span id="show_url" onclick="showURL();" class="nolite">Blocked URL</span>
<span id="show_filtered" onclick="showFiltered();" class="nolite">Authorized System</span>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<td nowrap>
<select name="selectFilter" id="selectFilter" size="23">
<option>test1</option>
<option>test2</option>
<option>test3</option>
</select>
</td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Via an AJAX call I am updating selectFilter options value successfully. But the issue is that the select box comes at the left hand side from menu options and does not expand much to cover the browser window. I have attached how the result page looks :[image: Resulet Page]

How can I make the select option to be displayed below my menu option and cover the browser window with margins left from bottom, top (after menu top), left and right?

Below is the CSS that I am using:

```
#icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 400px;
}

#ok_btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cancel_btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
}

#show_all, #show_words, #show_ip, #show_url, #show_filtered {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hilite {
  background: #f88017;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nolite {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.denied {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#table {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 60px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a styling issue you need to post your stylesheets as well

Comment: I have added my stylesheet in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your stylesheets but adding this will make it cover browser with margins.

```
table { width:96%;margin:1% ;}
select {width:100%}
```

Comment: I have added my stylesheet in the question. I tried to make use of your comments in my stylesheet but still the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the hint - with manipulation of my CSS I was able to achieve the objective